# SQL 80% percentile of discrete distribution

Tags: sql, statistics

Let's say we have SQL table with people's names and ages. (let's say age is an integer)

```
John 23 y.o.
Alex 45 y.o.
Anna 33 y.o.
etc.
```

We want to find 80% percentile of age. What's the function that calculates that? Such age that 80% of people are younger than that.

Also, which number we should return, if we have a discrete distribution? E.g. if we take age 40, exactly 77% are younger than that, and if we take age 41, exactly 82% people are younger than that. Which number between 40 and 41 should we return?

Sorry for a beginner question, couldn't find an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the 80th percentile of age by calculating it directly.  There are a lot of ways.  One method uses `ntile()`:

```
select min(age)
from (select ntile(100) over (order by age) as tile, age
      from t
     ) t
where tile = 80;
```

`ntile()` is a function that breaks a value into equal sized groups (in this case 100).  The minimum of the 80th group is usually good-enough for the 80th percentile.